# xmlHttpRequest GET for responseType arraybuffer gets empty response in electron

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, electron, arraybuffer

I am using electron version 1.7.9.
I need to download a zip file in my app.
Following code is used for the same.

```js
 var urlFetch = <path to the zip file I want to download>
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', urlFetch, true);
 xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
 xhr.onloadend = function () {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status == 200) {
            if (undefined !== xhr.response) {
                successCallback(xhr.response);
            } else {
                failureCallback();
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to fetch " + urlFetch + ", status - " + status);
            failureCallback();
        }
    };
 xhr.send();
```

On Windows 10 as well as on MacOs HighSierra, this code always gets undefined xhr.response in spite of status being 200.

xhr.responseText is populated with string, but what I need is the binary data of the zip file that I can use to store into a file for further use.

I have also tried adding following, but with no success.

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
```

Is there anything missing in the way I am coding or is this a bug in electron/chrome etc.?

The same code works perfectly outside of electron in a stand alone HTML.

Comment: What should occur with array buffer once the file is set at `.response`?

Comment: I would like to save that data to a file and read it back sometime later.

Comment: The request is successful at Chromium 63 at *nix. You can use JSZip to read `.zip` files

Comment: I can use JSZip to read the file *provided* I could write it, *provided* I get the binary data in my xhr.response - which is what is *not* happening.

Comment: Why do you check `status` within `onloadend` function? You should be able to use `xhr.onloadend = function () {
   console.log(xhr.response)
 };`. Is the resource served with CORS headers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the node js module xmlHttpRequest which was included.
Things started working when I removed this module.
I was not able to see the XHR requests in the "network" tab of dev tools in my electron app.
After removing the module, I can now see the requests and things work as desired.